# Two onPointerOver events conflict in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My screen is divided in two zones: left zone and right zone.
The left zone appears always. When you point over the left zone, it should make appear the right zone.
Once the right zone is displayed, both zones should make the right zone display.
But its not working as expected, the right zone disappear when "trying" to point over it.

Check the demo [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-brook-f9bwe?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [pointOverLeftZone, setPointOverLeftZone] = useState(false);
  const [pointOverRightZone, setPointOverRightZone] = useState(false);

  const shouldDisplayRightZone = pointOverLeftZone || pointOverRightZone;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="zone light-cyan"
        onPointerOver={() => {
          if (!pointOverLeftZone) setPointOverLeftZone(true);
        }}
        onPointerOut={() => {
          if (pointOverLeftZone) setPointOverLeftZone(false);
        }}
      >
        <p>Point over here to display the right zone</p>
      </div>
      {shouldDisplayRightZone && (
        <div
          className="zone light-yellow"
          onPointerOver={() => {
            if (!pointOverRightZone) setPointOverRightZone(true);
          }}
          onPointerOut={() => {
            if (pointOverRightZone) setPointOverRightZone(false);
          }}
        >
          <p>
            Once open the right zone, both zones should activate the display of
            this right zone, but the bug is here: when you mouse the move here
            it dissapear
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Value of `shouldDisplayRightZone` depends on value of `pointOverLeftZone`, `pointOverRightZone` so you should make it an independent state and wrap into an `useEffect` and update whenever there are changes in `pointOverLeftZone`, `pointOverRightZone`

```
const [shouldDisplayRightZone, setShouldDisplayRightZone] = useState(
  pointOverLeftZone || pointOverRightZone
);

useEffect(() => {
  setShouldDisplayRightZone(pointOverLeftZone || pointOverRightZone);
}, [pointOverLeftZone, pointOverRightZone]);
```

Forked codesandbox

[image: Edit exciting-sanderson-r13dk]

Comment: Clean but the right zone flash a bit with this implementation :( Also I wonder if I need an additional state when using a derived value from the state

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [pointOverLeftZone, setPointOverLeftZone] = useState(false);
  const [pointOverRightZone] = useState(false);

  const shouldDisplayRightZone = pointOverLeftZone || pointOverRightZone;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="zone light-cyan"
        onPointerOver={() => setPointOverLeftZone(true)}
      >
        <p>Point over here to display the right zone</p>
      </div>
      {shouldDisplayRightZone && (
        <div
          className="zone light-yellow"
          onPointerOut={() => setPointOverLeftZone(false)}
        >
          <p>
            Once open the right zone, both zones should activate the display of
            this right zone, but the bug is here: when you mouse the move here
            it dissapear
          </p>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
 import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
const [pointOverLeftZone, setPointOverLeftZone] = useState(false);
 const [pointOverRightZone, setPointOverRightZone] = useState(false);
const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);
const [int, setIni] = useState(false);
 const shouldDisplayRightZone = pointOverLeftZone || pointOverRightZone;

return (
<div className="App">
  {flag === true ? (
    <div
      className="zone light-cyan"
      onPointerOver={() => {
        if (!pointOverLeftZone) {
          setPointOverLeftZone(true);
        }
      }}
    >
      <p>Point over here to display the right zone</p>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <div>right zone open</div>
      <p>
        Once open the right zone, both zones should activate the display of
        this right zone, but the bug is here: when you mouse the move here
        it dissapear
      </p>
    </div>
   )}

   {shouldDisplayRightZone && (
     <div
      className="zone light-yellow"
      onPointerOver={() => {
        if (!pointOverRightZone) {
          setFlag(false);
          setPointOverRightZone(true);
        }
      }}
      onPointerOut={() => {
        if (pointOverRightZone) setPointOverRightZone(false);
      }}
    >
      <p>
        Once open the right zone, both zones should activate the display of
        this right zone, but the bug is here: when you mouse the move here
        it dissapear
      </p>
    </div>
   )}
 </div>
 );
 }
```

i have changed the code in sandbox you can check it there.Let me know if it works